# Is there an official host uri for Gitlab API?

Tags: gitlab

is it possible to use Gitlab API for official Gitlab Server? I mean `www.gitlab.com`. I can't find the host URI. Here is the api:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While [the documention](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/) does mention `https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/...`, you are still able to apply that API to gitlab.com itself.

You would use urls like `https://gitlab.com/api/v3/...` as described in [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/576)

```
 https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects?private_token=...
```

Or [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/support-forum/issues/301) (for creating a new project):

```
 curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: my token" -d "name=test" "https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects"
```

Comment: I'll check that out when I get back home. It must have been very late yesterday :). Still I don't understand why they use gitlab.example instead of the official one

Comment: Using gitlab.com should be part of the official documentation (at least in parallel with `gitlab.example.com`). Thank you.

Comment: any idea for the self hosted gitlab?Do we get an option to enable APIs. I am not using the official gitlab portal.

Comment: @SachinSingh https://gitlab.example.com/api/v3/... should work (replacing `gitlab.example.com` by your own server name).